# Choosing 3 squares from a $ n\times n$ grid such that no two are on the same diagonal

Tags: combinatorics

I would appreciate some pointers on this problem about finding the number of ways to choose 3 squares from an $n\times n$ grid such that no two are on the same diagonal.

This is http://oeis.org/A172123, where an explicit formula is given, but I am not sure how to derive that formula. Unfortunately the reference by Karl Fabel is in German and I cannot read German.

Comment: The correct reference is to [A172124](http://oeis.org/A172124); your link is for two bishops.

Answer (score 2):

(I'm going to use the chess-based language that the OEIS uses but you've abandoned, because I find it a much more natural way of talking about this kind of problem.)

Say we want to place three bishops on an $n \times n$ board so that two of them *are* attacking each other. We start by picking a diagonal, and then place two bishops on that diagonal and a third one somewhere on the board not on the diagonal. Note that there are four diagonals of each length, except there are only two of length $n$. So the total number of attacking situations of this type is 
$$A_n=2 {n \choose 2}(n^2-n) + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 4{n - k \choose 2}(n^2-n+k)\, .$$
There are two special cases we need to patch up.

First, we haven't counted configurations where all three bishops are on the same diagonal. A similar argument says that there are
$$B_n= 2 {n \choose 3} + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 4{n - k \choose 3}$$
such configurations.

Second, we've double-counted the "V-shaped" configuration where one bishop attacks the other two along different diagonals. This is the complicated case. We place the central bishop somewhere on the board, and pick a square on each of its diagonals to place the other two; in order to do this, we need to break it up by parity.

If $n$ is even, we can suppose by symmetry that the central bishop is in the upper-left quadrant of the board and then just multiply everything by 4. Say it has coordinates $(k,l)$ with $k,l \leq n/2$ (here the coordinates of the board squares range from $1$ to $n$). Then it lies on one diagonal which has $n-1-|k-l|$ other squares, and another which has $k+l-2$ other squares. Putting all this together, we can see that there are a total of 
$$C_n=4\sum_{k=1}^{n/2}\sum_{l=1}^{n/2} (k+l-2)(n-1-|k-l|)$$
configurations that look like this.

If $n$ is odd, a similar argument applies except that we also have to count configurations where the central bishop is on the middle rank or file of the board, which have a different set of symmetries. I won't go into the details at the moment, but hopefully by now you're convinced that this is possible (if tedious).

So then the total number of configurations where they *aren't* attacking each other is
$${n^2 \choose 3} - A_n - B_n + C_n$$
by inclusion-exclusion. Hopefully I haven't screwed up and this should evaluate to the formula in the OEIS; certainly it has the right basic properties (it's parity-dependent, and if you squint at it long enough you should be able to convince yourself that the two parity cases are both sextic polynomials in $n$).